# Use AJAX with Zend Framework 2

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I want to use AJAX with Jquery in my ZF2 project. Exactly, I want to change select options when an over select value change.

For this, I try to implement AJAX method. I don't find a good tutorial on internet for my problem, but I try to do this with different sources. This is my code :

Controller :

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    $contextSwitch = $this->_helper->getHelper('contextSwitch');
    $contextSwitch ->addActionContext('getcurrenttime', 'json')->initContext();
}

public function getcurrenttimeAction()
{
    $date = new Zend_Date();
    $chaine = $date->toString();
    $this->_helper->json($chaine);
}
```

This is my my route configuration :

```
 'administratif_personnel' => array(
            'type' => 'Literal',
            'priority' => 1000,
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/administratif/personnel',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Administratif\Controller\Personnel',
                    'action'     => 'liste',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                [...]
                'getcurrenttime' => array(
                    'type' => 'Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/getcurrenttime',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Administratif\Controller\Personnel',
                            'action'     => 'getcurrenttime',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

And this is my Jquery code in a view (depend of the same controller) I try to do two different method :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*
 * Initialisation de Jquery
 */
$().ready(function() {
    getCurrentTime();
});
function getCurrentTime() {
    $.post("/administratif/personnel/getcurrenttime",{"format":"json"}, function(resp){
        alert("test");
        alert(resp);
    },"json");

    $.ajax({
      url: "/administratif/personnel/getcurrenttime",
    }).done(function(t) {
        console.debug(t);
      console.debug("test");
    });
}
```

The first method with `$.post` don't work. I have no any return. But the `$.ajax` return me a html page. The `console.debug(t)` send me `<html><head>....</head></html>`. A page of my website.

Do you have any idea ? I think it's a problem with the route ?

Thank you!

Comment: `new Zend_Date() ` its from ZF1 there is no date library in ZF2

Comment: Is your question about ZF1 or ZF2?

Comment: It's the same with this : $chaine = "toto";
  $this->_helper->json($chaine);

Comment: My Question is about ZF2

Comment: You will need to disable the view layout for AJAX requests (`$view->setTerminal(true)` in a controller) to prevent the full markup being returned. Also you will need to add the `JsonViewStrategy` to ensure your response is JSON content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, you need to update a select value depending on the change of another value. So just bind onchange function to the select that changes, get the selected value and send it via AJAX to your Controller action so that you could get the new value and update the second select.

Hers is a solution that you could use in ZF2 :

**JS:**

```
$.ajax({ 
    type : 'POST',
    url : '/administratif/personnel/getcurrenttime',
    data : {value: changedValue},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){  
             //success function
             //current date is in data.currentdate
    },
    error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
             var error = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
             var content = error.content;
             console.log(content.message);
             if(content.display_exceptions)
             console.log(content.exception.xdebug_message);
    },

}) ;
```

**Controller:**

```
public function getcurrenttimeAction()
{
    //get the dependent value sent via ajax
    $value = $this->getRequest()->getPost('value');
    // your logic here....

    $date = date('Y-m-d'); // get the current date
    $data = new JsonModel(array(
            'currentdate' => $date,
    ));
    return $data;
}
```

You need also to enable `ViewJsonStrategy` in your `module.config.php` :

```
'view_manager' => array(
        //.............

        'strategies' => array(
            'ViewJsonStrategy',
        ),
),
```

Comment: I have a result in error part, not in success part of the ajax code. In jqXHR.responseText, i have alaways a html page. the html page of the index of my site : http://www.example.com. Thanks for your help

Comment: textStatus : parsererror
errorThrown : Unexpected token <

Comment: jquery expects json data type. Have you enabled `ViewJsonStrategy` in your module.config.php?